# awk: match one field until another field

Tags: regex, awk, field

I need to get records from a file that contains specific fields between one and other. Example:

> "**Mozart** was born on 27 January **1756** to Leopold Mozart (1719–1787) and Anna Maria, née Pertl (1720–1778), at 9 Getreidegasse"

I need to get only the fields between **Mozart** and **1756** (was born on 27 January)

Comment: Post a FEW lines of sample input and expected output plus a description of the algorithm you need or we're just guessing about your requirements and you're likely to get a solution that'll work for that 1 line of input but not for your general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` would do:

```
awk -F"Mozart | 1756" '{print $2}' file
was born on 27 January
```

If you like with all the words:

```
grep -oP 'Mozart .*? 1756' file
Mozart was born on 27 January 1756
```

Comment: I need the output with the specific field (Mozart and 1756) BUT thank you very much anyway.

Comment: @aresardido Thanks for accepting answer, I have updated it with a `grep` solution

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked specifically for `awk`:

```
echo "Mozart was born on 27 January 1756 to Leopold Mozart (1719–1787) and Anna Maria, née Pertl (1720–1778), at 9 Getreidegasse" | awk ' match($0, /Mozart(.*)1756/) { print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-10) }'
```

prints

```
 was born on 27 January
```

Comment: I think this is specific for this case and I need a general algorithm. Thank you!